Outlier detection for data set comparison
I have two data sets with similar columns, one numerical and the rest categorical.
col_1= categorical: city_name,
col_2= categorical: company_name,
col_3 = categorical: product_name,
col_4 = numerical : volume.
The number of rows is around 5000.
city_name has around 300-400 unique values, the company name has around 10 unique values and there are 5 different types of products with product 'a' being the most common type of product. Volume is unique for each col_1, col_2, col_3 combination (sum over last 12 months).
Let's call the first dataset df1 and the second df2. The hypothesis is that df1 is similar to df2 after removing outliers from df2. Before removing outliers the two data sets show quite different numbers in terms of descriptive statistics.
After manually removing outliers from df2 based on scatterplots, df1 and df2 have more similar descriptive statistics.
We believe that our outliers in df2 are coming from data that we currently don't have access to. Hence removing these outliers are currently based on a 'data-domain-expert-knowledge' i.e., a person with domain knowledge who looks at the scatter plots and decides.
My question is, would it be possible to do this outlier detection in a more sophisticated way? I have been looking into k-nn algorithm and tried to translate the categorical values into id's/numbers and came up with a bit of a random outlier selection heavily influenced by volume and neighbourhoods.
So my question is what would be a good way for ny particular case for a sophisticated outlier detection model? Any advice is appreciated.

If your person with expert knowledge can codify their rule, then it should be possible to write that into a program. Whatever that person is doing may be quite sophisticated.
I'd be very leery of any sort of automatic outlier detection such as number of SDs from mean or some measure of distance on the scatterplot. Such tools may help identify points for investigation, but should generally not be used in an automatic way.
Your note about "data we don't have access to" may point to other methods of data cleaning; if you can, somehow, tell which data you don't have access to before running analyses, you may be able to remove those points even if they are not outliers. This strikes me as good practice, if you can do it.

Great reply, thanks a lot it makes sense to do it in a more controlled way. I am new to this particular data domain I am currently in, but it seems like it is extremely hard to make general rules without a bunch of contradictions telling you that your rules does not take care of the special case x or y, which is why coding in my coworkers knowledge is challenging. I like your last idea as well, we could probably come up with some rule based on category column combinations.

If given my two data sets with the three categorical columns and one numerical, what would be a standard way to 'compare' the two data sets if we ignore the outliers for a while?         If we could deduce that df1 is 'isomorphic' to df2, then we have a great result, because then we can deduce a lot from other data sets based on df2.

For your second comment, I don't know the answer. You could ask it as a separate question. Many people don't read comments.
